# Combine sets of 2 rows based on different values of variables

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, tibble

I have the following table (a `tibble`)

| Year | Name | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1969 | Alice | 24 |
| 1969 | Bob | 25 |
| 1969 | Charlie | 33 |
| 1970 | Alice | 13 |
| 1970 | Bob | 20 |
| 1970 | Charlie | 10 |
| 1971 | Alice | 23 |
| 1971 | Bob | 10 |
| 1971 | Charlie | 16 |

etc.

I want to combine "Bob" and "Charlie" into a single row for each year by summing their value for `n` and give them a new name "Derek" (it makes more sense in my actual data). So I want

| Year | Name | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1969 | Alice | 24 |
| 1969 | Derek | 58 |
| 1970 | Alice | 13 |
| 1970 | Derek | 30 |
| 1971 | Alice | 23 |
| 1971 | Derek | 26 |

I have tried figuring out how to do it with `aggregate()` and `case_when()`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can first replace the names with Derek. Then  `summarise` to `sum` the ns from the doubles, grouped `.by` Name and Year.

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
    mutate(Name = case_match(Name, c("Bob", "Charlie") ~ "Derek",
                            .default = Name)) |>
    summarise(n = sum(n), .by = c(Year, Name))

  Year  Name  n
1 1969 Alice 24
2 1969 Derek 58
3 1970 Alice 13
4 1970 Derek 30
5 1971 Alice 23
6 1971 Derek 26
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, you can use `count(..., wt = n)` to sum `n` up by `Year` and the new `Name`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(Year, Name = replace(Name, Name %in% c("Bob", "Charlie"), "Derek"), wt = n)

#   Year  Name  n
# 1 1969 Alice 24
# 2 1969 Derek 58
# 3 1970 Alice 13
# 4 1970 Derek 30
# 5 1971 Alice 23
# 6 1971 Derek 26
```